# Magento - implement free shipping at pre-discount price

Tags: price-rules, free-shipping

***Customer gets free shipping if the selling price is more than 50USD.***

We currently have an offer on the site for 25% off. We want to offer free shipping at the original price.

As an **example**, consider I have a product which costs 60USD. Due to this, it qualifies for free shipping, however as the sale-price is less than the free-shipping price, the customer is charged shipping).

Is this even possible in Magento? I can't figure out a way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could go with adding a second pricerule for these specific products or based on a extra attribute. Freeshipping -> Yes.

So the rule would be if more than one product in the cart has the attribute Freeshipping yes